# the tangent bundle of an $m$-dimensional manifold is $2m$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

It is often taken as obvious that for $m$-dimensional manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$TM$ is a $2m$-dimensional manifold in $T\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$. But still is there an argument for the dimensinality number $2m$?

Comment: (translation issue: variété différentielle ---> manifold,  variété algébrique ---> variety)

Comment: Locall on $M$, for each $p\in M$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, so that a chart of $U$ maps it homeomorphically to some $D\subset \Bbb R^n$ (there should be one letter, please correct and use either $m$, or $n$), so that the projection $TU\to U$ becomes $D\times \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$. And $D\times \Bbb R^n$ is obviously of dimension $2n$.

Comment: @dan_fulea I think that there should be two letters $m$ and $n$. The $m$-dimensional manifold sits in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $m\leq n$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether this claim is obvious or not depends on the definition you've been given of the tangent bundle to a manifold. The "one-line proof" is: dimension is local, $M$ is locally $\mathbb{R}^m$, and you already agree that the tangent bundle to $\mathbb{R}^m$ itself has dimension $2m$.

However, it's possible that your definition of tangent bundle doesn't make it clear how the dimension of the tangent bundle is preserved by homeomorphism. So what you should show (using whatever definition of tangent bundle you have) is: for a point $p \in M$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with a homeomorphism $\phi: U \stackrel{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{R}^m$, $\phi$ induces a homeomorphism from the tangent bundle to $M$, restricted to $U$, to the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^m$.